# Can one simplify $\arctan(a\tan(x))$?

Tags: trigonometry

We know that $\arctan(\tan(x))=x$ when $x$ lies between $-\pi/2$ and $+\pi/2$; but do you know a way to transform the expression $\arctan(a\tan(x))$, where $a$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$?

I thought $a$ could be transformed with trigonometric functions, such as $a=\sin(\alpha)\cos(x)$, but $\arctan(\sin(\alpha)\sin(x))$ does not remind me anything.

Maybe there is no further possible transformation?

Comment: You can consider finding the [Taylor series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+arctan%28a+tan+x%29) of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can convert the arctan to other inverse-trig functions, such as arcsin:

$$ \arctan(a \tan(x)) = \arcsin\left(\frac{a \sin(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)^2 + a^2 \sin(x)^2}}\right) $$

Comment: Thanks, but not easy to manipulate. By the way, I browsed WolframAlpha and found no practical alternative formula. I guess the question is hopeless...

Comment: May I ask how could we get the arcsin formula, thanks.

Comment: If $\tan(\theta) = t$, $\sin(\theta) = \tan(\theta) \cos(\theta) = \frac{t}{\pm \sqrt{1+t^2}}$.  If $-\pi/2 < \theta <\pi/2$, the $\pm$ is $+$.